# Simple Date Format parsed then formatted date didn't match

Tags: java, date, datetime

I've run into a strange behavior of SimpleDateFormat, i don't know how to deal with.

I need to parse a date in a specific format (Day of Week, then day, then Month, then Year, Then time).
However, I've run into a behaviour, when parsing a date gives me a very strnge result (other date). Here is a small, self-contained example, and it's output on my machine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    test("E YYYY kk:mm:ss");
    test("E d YYYY kk:mm:ss");
    test("E d MMMM YYYY kk:mm:ss");
}

public static void test(String format) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println(now);
    String formattedNow = sdf.format(now);
    System.out.println(formattedNow);
    Date parsedFormattedNow = sdf.parse(formattedNow);
    String formattedParsedNow = sdf.format(parsedFormattedNow);
    System.out.println(formattedParsedNow);
    System.out.println(formattedNow.equals(formattedParsedNow));
}
```

Output:

```
Sat Apr 27 13:48:07 MSK 2013
Sat 2013 13:48:07
Sat 2013 13:48:07
true
Sat Apr 27 13:48:07 MSK 2013
Sat 27 2013 13:48:07
Sat 5 2013 13:48:07
false
Sat Apr 27 13:48:07 MSK 2013
Sat 27 April 2013 13:48:07
Sat 5 January 2013 13:48:07
false
```

Why do then 27 transforms into 5, and April to January?

Comment: Replace `Y` with `y` and [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are two aspects here:

- The pattern `E d YYYY kk:mm:ss` doesn't contain a month indicator at all. So after formatting to "Sat 27 2013 13:48:07" how are you expecting the parsing part to work out the month?
- All your patterns use `YYYY` which is the week-year, not calendar year. This should usually be used with "day of week, week of week-year" patterns. If you use `yyyy` instead, the final pattern will work.

The only reason the first pattern *appears* to work is that you're not actually setting anything other than the "day of week" and the year (and time, of course). If you print out `parsedFormattedNow` (with no other formatting) you'll see that the parse result is actually January 5th. It's just you don't notice it, because it's still a Saturday.